# Rss feed operation timed out

Tags: asp.net, rss, xmldocument

I am trying to load the digg favorites rss items. But getting error as operation timed out.
Please let me know if anyone have solved this issue before.

```
    Public Shared Function HasRssItems() As Boolean
        Dim doc As New XmlDocument
        doc.Load("http://digg.com/users/Lovelezz/history/favorites.rss")
        Return doc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item").Count > 0
   End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you are behind a proxy that isn't letting you through. You will have set up your proxy settings.

[Here is an article that describes it.](http://bansky.net/blog/2007/10/fetching-url-via-default-proxy-in-c-sharp/)

*Edit: updated article.*